# jquery sortable placeholder height problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

For some reason the placeholder for my sortable items is about 10px.  All my sortable items have different heights.  How can I change the height of each placeholder to match the item being moved?

Comment: Can you post it to jsFiddle ?

Comment: Is this happened when you just drag and drop your item to another place? or the items already have this height after loading the page? anyway take a look here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4482 and try to workaround as mentioned

Answer (score 269, accepted):

I usually solve this by binding a callback that sets the height of the placeholder to the height of the item being sorted to the [`start`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-start) event. It's a simple solution that gives you fine-grained control over how you want your placeholder to be displayed.

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    start: function(e, ui){
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
    }
});
```

See  [updated test case](http://jsfiddle.net/t8gcZ/1/)

Comment: I personally had to replace ui.item.height() with ui.helper.outerHeight() due to some issues with margins and padding skewing the actual height of the element

Comment: sorry but i don't think it work well, in this link http://jsfiddle.net/t8gcZ/1/, placeholder height is same to item height (237px) but at the started time, we could see the under item moved up a litter

Comment: @Makio That's because of the padding-bottom. Adding padding-bottom to the placeholder solves this. http://jsfiddle.net/t8gcZ/136/

Comment: Why is this answer so hard to find. I've been searching for days and finally came upon this post. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried setting the `forcePlaceholderSize:true` property? Have a read on the jQuery UI Sortable [documentation page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-forcePlaceholderSize).

Comment: i have tried that, but adding true or false makes no difference to my original site which keeps it at 10px high.  in this jsfiddle, it resizes correctly, but forceplaceholdersize set to true or false makes no difference. http://jsfiddle.net/t8gcZ/

Comment: @oshirowanen: What browser are you testing it under?

Comment: @oshirowanen: Can you post a link to the code where it's actually broken?

Comment: That does work for me. All I had to do was change the CSS `.ui-sortable-placeholder { border: 1px dotted black; visibility: visible !important; height: 50px !important; }` to `.ui-sortable-placeholder { border: 1px dotted black; visibility: visible !important; }` (so remove the height) So @DarthJDG you are right!

Comment: @JPHellemons that only works if the height is not dynamic

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using "ui.item.height()" you can use "ui.helper[0].scrollHeight" to stable result when drag an item from external container too.

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    start: function(e, ui){
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper[0].scrollHeight);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Are your elements `display: block` ? Inline elements might make the placeholder not keep the height correctly. Eg. [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CnSSv/) seems to have a similar problem to the one you described. Adding `display: block` to the `.portlet` class fixes it.

Comment: Same goes for floating elements. If the list elements are floating, the placeholder should float too.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I found solution similar to [JP Hellemons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140680/jquery-sortable-placeholder-height-problem#comment8137654_6142369), in which I'm forcing height of placeholder (with *!important*) to custom and also setting visibility with background to see changes for myself (also you can style this way your placeholder anyhow you want).

This works also with `display: inline-block;`

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder { 
     background:red !important; 
     height: 2px !important; // this is the key, set your own height, start with small
     visibility: visible !important;
     margin: 0 0 -10px 0; // additionaly, you can position your placeholder, 
     }                    // in my case it was bottom -10px
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a style for your placeholder as an option for your sortable.

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});
```

And just give that style a height. Hope that works.

Comment: But won't that fix the height?  I need the hight to be the same as the content.